# no me reconoce la variable $traduccion, ¿que hago?

Tags: php, html, mysql

** este es el codigo del otro archivo que enlaza con la base de datos**

```
<?php

$Chost = "localhost";
$Cuser = "root";
$Cpass = "";
$Cdb = "consulta";

$conex=new mysqli($Chost,$Cuser,$Cpass,$Cdb);
  if($conex->connect_errno){
    die("ha ocurrido un error");
}
?>
```

** esta parte del codigo vincula al archivo php aparte con el codigo de html :)**

```
  <?php

include("conectar.php");

?>
```

** este es el codigo que esta en el html y que se vincula con los botones y todo**

```
 <div id="traduccion"> <h3> <?php echo $traduccion; ?> </h3> </div>
 
  <?php

  if(isset($_GET['traducir'])){

    $busqueda=$_GET['introducir'];

    $traduccion=$conex->query("SELECT * FROM traducciones WHERE traduccion LIKE '%$introducir%'");

    while($row = $traduccion->fetch_array()){

      echo $row['traduccion'];
    }
  }
  ?>
```

** bueno, ahi esta el codigo completo**

Comment: Qué quieres hacer? Estás intentando usar la variable antes de declararla

Comment: quiero que me traiga datos de una base de datos. la variable traduccion se supone que imprime el dato en el div. se aprieta un boton y te busca la palabra y te imprime un resultado a traves de $traduccion.

Comment: Saludos. Coloca el mensaje o aquello que "no te permite" usar esa variable.

Comment: perdon :'v soy un desastre. ahi edito la pregunta

Comment: debes tener en cuenta que el código se ejecuta secuencialmente. Ahora mismo estás intentando imprimir el resultado antes de hacer la consulta a la base de datos. Deberías imprimir las traducciones dentro del `while`

Comment: es decir, como seria eso? muchas gracias y perdon por mi torpeza :) muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

El código se ejecuta secuencialmente, por lo que no puedes imprimir una variablemente que haz declarado más adelante.

Debes leer la variable después de haberle asignado el resultado.

Además como mencionó A.Cedano, tampoco está definida la variable `$introducir` que se usas en la consulta SQL. Probablemente quisiste poner `$busqueda`

```
<div id="traduccion">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['traducir'])){
  $busqueda=$_GET['introducir'];
  $traduccion=$conex->query("SELECT * FROM traducciones WHERE traduccion LIKE '%$busqueda%'");
  while($row = $traduccion->fetch_array()){
    echo "<h3>{$row['traduccion']}</h3>";
  }
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIASSSSSSSSSS <3 (sigue sin mostrar los resultados pero no me aparece mas el error <3)

Comment: si no muestra resultados es porque la consulta no devolvió ningún resultado

Comment: La variable `$introducir` que se usa en la instrucción SQL, tampoco se define en ningún momento... parecería que es la variable `$busqueda` la que debería usarse. Por otra parte, estamos ante un código débil, que no cubre ciertas situaciones como el hecho de que la consulta falle o no devuelva datos... El código tampoco informa cuando no entra en los isset. OP se queja de que *sigue sin mostrar los resultados*, ¿acaso hay que programar pensando que un código DEBE mostrar resultados sí o sí? Pues no, puede NO mostrar resultados y en ese caso debes afrontar el problema e informar al usuario.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por la aclaración. No le había prestado atención al código. Sobre el manejo de errores tal vez sea muy pronto para introducirlo. El OP está haciendo su primera conexión a una base de datos y probablemente si espera obtener resultados. El código tiene varias malas prácticas y es vulnerable pero está bien para ser un ejercicio de práctica.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto, pero creo importante que OP comprenda desde un primer momento que un código no tiene por qué darte los resultados esperados. En un contexto tan simple como este el código puede fallar por al menos tres motivos (en cuanto a la lógica) y la tarea de un programador es prever también esos posibles fallos y cubrirlos adecuadamente. Ya luego se hablará de manejo de errores, pero es importante que OP sea consciente de que hay fallos de lógica también, no solamente de sintaxis o de variables mal usadas. De hecho, aquí no salta el `Undefined variable` porque no entra en el `if`.